# Trigger new content with Isotope and get it to play well with new ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I am in the process of getting an infinite scroll w/ajax and the plugin isotope working.

I followed a tutorial found here http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/scroll-pagination/ which loads all of the content just fine and expected for the infinite scroll part of things.

My issue however is I dont know how to trigger the new content with Isotope to get it to play well with new content that was added.

Here is a link to the Isotope example of infinite scroll.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Any one have any experience with getting this to work?

The tutorial I followed would just need some type of callback I am guessing but have no idea where to start with that :/

Comment: Within the example, Inside the `getData()` function I took out the append data part and replaced it with `$(document).find('#posts').isotope( 'appended', $( data ) ); ` I thought that would add the new data while triggering the isotop event but it didnt work

Comment: Well... first thing, you don't need to do `$(document).find('#posts')` the equivalent is just `$('#posts')`

Comment: Thanks, regardless if that was the issue it would have worked both ways... Found out the it cant be done with that plugin per the creator

Comment: Right, just a pointer. I am not really sure how to get it working on your end, because I don't know what you have. If you could recreate your issue on jsFiddle or something it would help